# A Component Error has occurred! when open page with Cypress.io

Tags: lws

When I open Page with LWC Component under Cypress.io test, then Salesforce returns error:

**A Component Error has occurred!**

> undefined is not a valid component, or does not extends
> LightningElement from "lwc". You probably forgot to add the extend
> clause on the class declaration.

**Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components** is enabled

[image]

Cypress code is simple:

```
describe('playground', () => {
  it('playground', function () {

    cy.request({
      body: {
        display: 'page',
        hasRememberUn: true,
        height: '1080',
        lt: 'standard',
        pw: Cypress.env('password'),
        un: Cypress.env('email'),
        useSecure: true,
        username: Cypress.env('email'),
        width: '2560',
      },
      form: true,
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://login.salesforce.com',
    })

    cy.visit('/lightning/n/TestCypressPage')
  })
})
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: does it work when you manually navigate to that URL?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, if I open this page manually, then such an error does not appear. There is a suspicion that Cypress cannot access the LWC correctly.